# Hover Effect Not Working on Active Button in CSS with Button onclick JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple HTML/CSS/JS tutorial, and I've encountered an issue where the hover effect is not working on a button when it has the 'active' class. I understand the best practice is to separate HTML and JavaScript, but for this tutorial, I am using inline JavaScript for simplicity. I'm aware that in typical scenarios, using `addEventListener` for handling events in JavaScript is the recommended approach. However, for specific reasons related to this tutorial, I am using inline JavaScript within the `onclick` attribute.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```css
.active {
   background-color: #cc0000 !important;  
}
#button3, #button4 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#button3:hover, #button4:hover {
  background-color: green;
}


#button3.active:hover, #button4.active:hover {
  background-color: blue;  
}
```

```html
<button id="button3" class="active" onclick="this.classList.add('active'); document.getElementById('button4').classList.remove('active');">Size: Small</button>
<button id="button4" onclick="this.classList.add('active'); document.getElementById('button3').classList.remove('active');">Size: Large</button>
```

I've tried increasing the specificity of the hover selector and ensuring the order of CSS rules, but the issue persists. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the hover effect is not working on the active button and how to fix it.

Comment: The effect appears to be working as expected in the code snippet above.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You've said it's "not working", but not what that means. What should be happening that's not? What's happening that should not? See [ask] for more tips on asking good questions.

Comment: Your question mentions hover, but your code is using `onclick` and I think you are getting confused between the two. It does seem to be working, so what's the issue?

Comment: Hello everyone, please refresh the page. I forgot to add !important to the .active class in the CSS rule background-color: #cc0000 !important;. Now, the JavaScript for changing the background color is working correctly. However, the issue we now face is with the hover background color for the active button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) keyword after the background color on hover will get you the result that you want.

```css
.active {
   background-color: #cc0000 !important;  
}
#button3, #button4 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


#button3:hover, #button4:hover {
  background-color: green;
}


#button3.active:hover, #button4.active:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;  
}
```

```html
<button id="button3" class="active" onclick="this.classList.add('active'); document.getElementById('button4').classList.remove('active');">Size: Small</button>
<button id="button4" onclick="this.classList.add('active'); document.getElementById('button3').classList.remove('active');">Size: Large</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, @YT_Xaos. It works. I am not sure why I did not try adding !important.

Answer (score 0):

Hover effect is working fine. But if you want to attach active class with the button after click event on the button, you could define the style for the element with classes, you have defined the css rules with ids. Ids have higher specificity over classes. So you could changes in your css `#button3` `#button4` with `.button3` `.button4`. For your `.active` class definition should come after defining the initial styles for `.button3`,`.button4`.

```css
    .button3,.button4 {
    ...
    }
    .active{
    ...
    }
```

Change all references of ids with classes in css. For html, use both id and classes.

```html
<button  id = "button3" class="button3 active"  onclick="this.classList.add('active'); document.getElementById('button4').classList.remove('active');">Size: Small</button>
<button id="button4" class="button4" onclick="this.classList.add('active'); document.getElementById('button3').classList.remove('active');">Size: Large</button>
```

Comment: This answer does not correctly answer OP's question.